# Getting syntax error while cleaning data using ast.literal_eval()

Tags: python, regex, syntax-error, data-cleaning, mfcc

I have extracted data set from librosa library.

[This is top five data.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pqbri.png)

[These are the total columns.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5ySh.png)

These data are in object format.

[It has got '\n' and spaces and all. So, it is needed to be cleaned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYgXy.png)

```
import ast
import numpy as np
import re

#  removing \n and converting into number format
if '\n' in df['MFCC_1'][0]:
    row = df['MFCC_1'][0]        
    row = ast.literal_eval(re.sub('\s+', ",", df['MFCC_1'][0].replace('\n', '')))

print(row)
```

This code is working but it gives syntax error in most cases.

[This is an error occurring in most cases.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPi9J.png)

---

After this I want to save each cleaned data to csv file in the same row and column format. So any suggestion for it too.

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed & replaced with `python` & `regex`).

Comment: You have an extra comma at the beginning of the row. Don't replace **ALL** the spaces with comma.

Comment: you can copy paste your data here instead of linking images to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Don't replace all the spaces but only when they are inbetween 2 digits:

```
if '\n' in df['MFCC_1'][0]:
    row = df['MFCC_1'][0].replace('\n', '')
    row = ast.literal_eval(re.sub(r'(?<=\d)\s+(?=\d)', ",", row))
```

Comment: This just gave one value in MFCC_1  **  [-76526.67412012005]  **
It also gives invalid syntax for other columns.